# Finding out the absolute path of the PHP interpreter running the current script

Tags: php, path, command-line-interface, environment

In the CLI mode, is it safe and portable to rely on `getenv('_')` for finding out which php interpreter executable is running the current php script? I don't see it documented anywhere on [php.net](http://php.net)

Comment: Wow! Never seen it before! BTW, that would work only for CLI...

Comment: Good point re CLI. I'll update the question.

Comment: Living in Winterthur!? I been living in Wädenswil and working in Horgen!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

constant of `PHP_BINDIR` should be more reliable
(I might be wrong)

A quick test I did show `getenv("_");` in fastcgi is `httpd` (no problem on CLI)

If you have PHP 5.4, then

```
PHP_BINARY
```

Answer (score 2):

[PHP_BINDIR](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) (string) - Specifies where the binaries were installed into.

Also, getenv('_') returns false on my windows